# Traffic shaping advice

Tags: wireless-router, ubuntu-11.04, bridge, wireless-bridge, traffic-shaping

I've been searching the topic I'm looking for for a quite some time, then I decide to ask my own question because I'm so confused right now.

First thing first, here is the background information you need to know. We are located in Luanda Angola, the internet here really sucks, I mean the current connecting we are using is a 1mbps 3G wireless network. Considering the poor speed we are thinking about upgrading to a satellite network with 10mbps boardband, here is the problem, according to the FAP (Fair Access Policy?) if the download within 72 hours excess 10% of monthly allowance (40GB per month in my case, so makes it 4GB per 72 hours) the internet connection will be slow to 64kbps. We don't want that to happen, therefore I'm looking for a easy way to shape our traffic.

Second, let's see what I have in hand, a laptop with one ethernet port and a wireless card. A wireless router, cheap one without any QoS. and basically that's it.

The current connection configuration is "3G wireless router(mifi) >>> wireless router >>> local devices" (">>>" indicates wireless connection, "---" wired connection)
I believe the wireless router is just expanding the existed wireless network provided by the 3G wireless router.

The Satellite broadband will come with its own router and the I guess the future configuration will be something like "Satellite Router --- wireless router >>> local devices"
here is the catch, I'm gonna put a linux box between satellite router and wireless router to monitor and control the overall traffic. For instance "Satellite --- Laptop >>> wireless router >>> local devices"

I'm been trying to setup a bridging network for my Laptop the eth0 and wan0, i'm not sure if that's feasible, then using mastershaper or something similar to setup all the traffic rules according to each devices' mac address.

So there is my question, is the bridge really necessary and feasible, and is there other tools for traffic shaping, I saw someone talking about iptables but I'm not sure I'm confident to set it up. Anyway, thanks for taking time reading this, and any input would be appreciated.